# Как быстро сделать нагрузочное тестирование с 20к конкурентных запросов?

Tags: highload, облако, веб-служба, сервер, тестирование

Можете подсказать платный (ограничение 30-40$) облачный сервис или десктопное решение, чтобы можно было просто иммитировать 20 000 пользователей, одновременно ползающих на сайте (точнее даже на 2-х страницах).

Мне не нужен тарифный план на месяц за 700$, мне нужно один раз протестировать, как сервер держит нагрузку.

Comment: 20000  одновременно -- как Вы представляете себе имитацию поведения пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Если нет желания тратить деньги на сервис, то можно подобное сделать с помощью jmeter(одной машины наверняка будет мало)
Вот примеры:
[Пример на хабре1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140310/)
[Пример на хабре2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/84190/)

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите Azure. Самая маленькая виртуальная машина стоит $0,018 в час. Создайте нужное количество и наслаждайтесь. Статут ненужны - удалите, оплата почасовая.